# Deindent Block in Sphinx literalinclude Directive

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a block of code in a file that I want to include in an example in Sphinx documentation, using a `literalinclude` directive.

But that code is in a function, so when I include it, in the example each line is indented by one level more than I'd like.

```
.. literalinclude:: ../../examples/example.py
   :language: python
   :lines: 13-42
   :tab-width: 0
```

Produces

```py
    import foo
    from foo import bar

    print("I'm indented too far")
```

Is there any other way to remove or deindent the literal block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`literalinclude` has a `dedent` option:

```
.. literalinclude:: ../../examples/example.py
   :language: python
   :lines: 13-42
   :tab-width: 0
   :dedent: 4
```

The option is mentioned under "Additional options" in the `literalinclude` documentation, but the details are in [the documentation for `code-block`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-option-code-block-dedent).